# inno setup install vb6 app dll

Tags: vb6, windows-vista, inno-setup

I recently compiled a vb6 application with inno setup that when i install, works fine on winxp
when i tried it on vista, i got error message

[image]

i noticed it was a dll registration problem, so i try to register the dll manually to see if it corrects the problem. when i tried that, i got this error

[image]

is there anyway i can correct the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vista computer might not have ActiveX Installer Service installed/enabled, see [Implementing and Administering the ActiveX Installer Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721964%28WS.10%29.aspx) for detail instructions.

Answer (score -1):

It's a permissions issue. Try the following:

Register the component from an elevated command prompt. Right click on the 
icon for Command Prompt on the start menu and select Run as Administrator. 
You will be prompted by UAC to approve the elevation. Once the command 
prompt window is open, run your regsvr32 command from that window and it 
should succeed.
Source: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/2009-10/msg00002.html

You can also try running the installer you just created with administrative privileges (same procedure as above). I hope that helps.

Comment: the installer is running under administrative privileged. what now?

Comment: What about manually installing the dll using elevated command prompt? You need to be shure there are no dependencies missing or any other problem before we move to fixing the Inno Setup script.

Comment: yes no dependency missing, and am using vista business with administrator account.